# unable to verify the first certificate - Nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I am calling an external Get method and getting this error "unable to verify the first certificate". How can I resolve it with Nestjs?

Answer (score -1):

Pay the SSL certificate on the endpoint? Call `http` instead of `https`? Probably not a good question to ask here tbh

Comment: It's in "external" endpoint, I am trying to integrate with a third party, I can't pay the SSL certificate for them tbh

Comment: @ant0h I am faing the same problem, were you able to figure out the solution?

Comment: @osama the problem was not from my end, and the third party that I was integrated with did not fix it, so I had to ignore SSL